# SMT Resistor Fails, but through-hole resistor of same value succeeds for op-amp band-pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, surface-mount

I am making a band-pass filter with a gain of 75v/v. Center frequency of 30k. Passband of ~30k. I used the analog wizard site (https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) to generate the band-pass circuit. Pictured are the band-pass info and the proposed circuit. I am using a +-5V power supply.
[image]
[image]

For the first stage of the band-pass filter (Stage A), when I use an SMT resistor of 22 ohms for R3, the circuit rails to the -5V power supply. However, when I used a through-hole resistor of the same value (22 ohms), the circuit works as intended. Below is the top view of my pcb. The resistor numbers dont match, but I have highlighted R17 to be equivalent to R3 in the opamp picture. [image] My guess is that the SMT resistor is forming a series capacitance with the ground plane below the resistor. I am relatively new to making PCBs, so any advice on improving my design would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which resistor corresponds to R4?

Comment: You need to rule out tolerances and there is also more than one kind of surface mount resistor and through-hole.

Comment: I confirmed that each are within 0.1 Ohms. I also confirmed that 18 ohms, 22 ohms, 27ohms, and 30ohms of TH resistor work, with the expected reduction or increase in gain. I have only checked the 22ohm for the SMT.
@Finbarr R5 and R18 make a resistance value of 940 (they form R4).

Comment: @DKNguyen I used this resistor (https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Chip-Resistor-Surface-Mount_UNI-ROYAL-Uniroyal-Elec-0603WAF220JT5E_C23345.html) for the SMT, and used a standard 1/4 W +-1% TH resistor as comparison. Measured each with a multimeter and found one TH that was within 0.1 ohm of the SMT. To Test the TH, I desoldered the SMT, and attached the TH resistor leads to the SMT pad.

Comment: By the sound of it, the SMT resistor wasn't making proper contact with the pads or one end was shorting with 0V. A bit of probing with a scope or a meter should identify the issue.

Comment: I thought that too, but I have multiple PCBs (5 ordered) and tested that the behavior is the same across all 5. I also resoldered the connection of the SMT resistor on a spare board with no change in behavior. I did not solder the original resistors, the factory did, so I am relatively confident that it is not a proper contact issue. I will recheck again to confirm.

Comment: Just confirmed, not a contact issue.

Comment: Is it a 2-layer board (not 4 or more)?

Comment: @Finbarr I went back after rechecking, and I redid the solder on the pads again for R17 for the 3rd time. That fixed it miraculously. For some reason, my previous resolders did not adhere to the pad. And it is the same problem across all 5 boards for the same resistor, so there must have been some issue with this particular resistor for this particular configuration.. If you propose your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you all for your help. I made the false assumption that the factory would correctly solder all the components, and I will no longer make that assumption.

Comment: Done. It may be that the resistor isn't quite sitting down on the pads if the solder resist doesn't have enough clearance.

Comment: As an improvement for future revs, I would increase the ground clearance around the parts.  Also, if your vias are not tented, then you could be getting a solder bridge to the that ground via.  I've also seen shorts to the edge of the ground plane, when the soldermask wasn't applied thick enough.  Increasing the clearance will help this.

Answer (score 3):

For capacitance to the ground plane to affect the operation of a 22 Ohm resistor at 100 kHz it would need to be in the tens of nanoFarads and that's way, way more than you'd ever get between tracks on PCB layers. In any case, it would just reduce the gain or attenuate the signal rather than send it to a supply rail.

It's far more likely that the resistor isn't being properly soldered to the board or there's a short somewhere. Some probing with a scope or a meter should reveal the problem.